# How do I Select/Click a text from textView which is on a listView that is set both OnItemClickListener and OnItemLongClickListener

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a listView of which items are populated from FirebaseListAdapter, Items might include a text, image, video or all. I have set **OnItemLongClickListener** on the listview so as to allow user to be able to delete a post,Also I have set **OnItemClickListener** to allow the user  to play a video incase an item in the listView includes a video. Everything works fine.

The problem is I want a user to be able to select a text from that list incase he/she wants to copy from that text or to click it incase it is an url. But the text can not be selected nor clicked,I know this is  caused by the **OnItemClicklistener** on the listView, How do I solve this to work as I want.

I have try to set

```
      android:textIsSelectable="true"
      android:autoLink="all"
```

But still I cannot select or click from the textView.

Below is the xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/frameMessage"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/message_text"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:autoLink="all"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:textColorLink="#009900"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
    android:textSize="13sp" />

 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/message_user"
    android:textColor="#00e5b8"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    android:textSize="12sp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/message_user"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:textColor="#b0abff"
    android:id="@+id/message_time"
    android:textSize="12sp"/>


<FrameLayout
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:foregroundGravity="center"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/frameMessage"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/message_time"
    >

    <VideoView
        android:background="#0000"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:id="@+id/videoMessage"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"
        android:layout_height="200dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:id="@+id/imageVideo"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"

        android:foregroundGravity="center"
        android:layout_height="200dp"

        />


    <ImageButton
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:id="@+id/btnMessage"
        android:layout_width="39dp"
        android:layout_height="39dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/iconplayblue" />
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBarMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try adding this attribute to this widget android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"

Comment: @ArunAbimanyu I have added that with no success, note that it is also added in the root parent Layout

Comment: That attribute should be added to your text view, not in root layout

Comment: Yes @ArunAbimanyu I have added it to the TextView, but it does not work it was also on root layout  before

Comment: Please remove that attribute in root layout

Comment: @ArunAbimanyu if I remove that from root layout, the OnItemClickListener and OnItemLongClickListener on listView does not respond